# 1 Insufficient cpu, 5 node(s) didn't match node selector

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

when I am trying to install a chart pods are getting stuck at pending state.

describe pods  give below error

```
Node-Selectors:  ads.open.com/elasticsearch=true
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
                 open.com/elasticsearch=true:NoSchedule
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/6 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 5 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

when I describe node which it should get schedule due to label

```
Labels:             ads.open.com/elasticsearch=true
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=nova
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=xx.xxx.xx.xx
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=true

Taints:             openet.com/elasticsearch=true:NoSchedule

Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-cinder:  256
  cpu:                        8
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-cinder:  256
  cpu:                        7600m
```

Comment: How much `cpu` does the pod in question request?

Comment: Also, for troubleshooting purposes please also add the `$ kubectl describe node XXX` and the `YAML` manifest your `Pod`/`Deployment`.

Comment: requests:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 2G
          limits:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 4G

Answer (score 1):

I added one more node with same taint and label redeployed chart. Error got resolved